# Jsoup: Get texts inside divs

Tags: java, jsoup

I have some trouble to get the texts in the following HTML code, I need some help please.

```
<div class="itemlist">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="Description">
            <h2>Item 1</h2>   // GET THIS
            <h3 title="Shipping :01-02 Nov">Shipping :01-02Nov</h3> // GET THIS
            </div>

            <div class="price" style="margin: 0px auto; display: none;">
            <span class="arial-12-88" style="display: inline;"></span>
            <div class="currency-USD arial-24-26-bold">450&nbsp;USD</div> // GET THIS
            <span class="arial-12-d0" style="display: inline;"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="button_set" style="display: flex;">
            <a href="productDetail.htm?pid=00020170918214914392zGPQW7nE06A2"><button class="learn">Learn More</button></a>
            <a href="user/orderDetails.htm?m=add&amp;pid=00020170918214914392zGPQW7nE06A2&amp;count=1&amp;fitting=">
            <button class="add">Add To Cart</button></a> // GET THIS                            
            </div>
        </li>
            next item ...           

    </ul>       
</div>

The output should be:
Item 1
Shipping :01-02Nov
450&nbsp;USD
```

My approach is too static and cannot handle changes in the item structure. Because not every item has e.g. the price on the same ChildNumber. The only equal things are the div class names.

I use at the moment as I used the debugger to find which child I have to call:

```
Element content = doc.getElementsByClass("itemlist").first();
Node child1 = content.childNode(1);
for (Node node : child1.childNodes()) {
    try {
        Node desc = node.childNode(3);
        Node price = node.childNode(5);
        Node stock = node.childNode(7);
        // get description
        Node desc_elem = desc.childNode(1);
        Node desc_text = desc_elem.childNode(0);
        String desc_txt = ((TextNode) desc_text).text().trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
```

Please help me to find a more dynamic way. Ideal would be to get all listitems and loop over them. Then call to get the div description, div price. Then I could read the text from the child.

Comment: I would start by reading official docs : https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html, did you tried `elem.text()` ?

Comment: I solved it very static with Element content = doc.getElementsByClass("itemlist").first(); and then go forther with Node child = content.childNode(1) and so on... would appreciate if someone could show me a more dynamic approach.

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you clarify this by editing your question? Also, is the HTML of each item repeating structurally, so the title is always in ```<h2>``` tags and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //select the div with the item list
    Element itemlist = doc.select("div.itemlist").first();
    // select each li element
    Elements items = itemlist.select("li");
    // for each li element select the corresponding div with item name, shipping info and price 
    for(Element e : items){
        System.out.println(e.select("div.Description h2").text());
        System.out.println(e.select("div.Description h3").text());
        System.out.println(e.select("div.currency-USD").text());
    }
```

Comment: Wow, really nice solution. I implemented it and it worked. Thank you very much!!!